# coldfusion less cumbersome way to create four structures based on array modulus

Tags: coldfusion, structure, modulus

I have an array "varray" which needs to be split into four structures.  The first of each four elements should be in structure 1, the second in structure 2, etc.  I have some working code to do this, but it feels to me like there should be a less cumbersome way.  Here is the code:

```
<cfset xord  = StructNew()>
<cfset xsort = StructNew()>
<cfset xsel  = StructNew()>
<cfset xmer  = StructNew()>

<cfloop from = '1' to = "#ArrayLen(varray)#" index = 'i'>
  <cfset fieldname = farray[i]> <!---farray previously defined --->
  <cfset val = varray[i]> <!---varray previously defined --->
 <cfset j = i%4>

 <cfif j EQ 1>
   <cfset xord[fieldname] = val>
 <cfselseif j EQ 2>
   <cfset xsort[fieldname]= val>
 <cfelseif j EQ 3>
   <cfset xsel[fieldname] = val>
 <cfelseif j EQ 0>
   <cfset xmer[fieldname] = val>
 </cfif>

</cfloop>
```

Can anyone suggest a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(You didn't mention your version, so I don't know if you have access to newer functions like array each(). Keep in mind there's slicker options in newer versions)

Instead of creating separate variables, create a single structure containing the 4 variables, and an array of names. Then use the array and MOD to populate the substructures. *Note, the example below creates the subsubstructures up front to ensure they always exist - even if the field/value arrays are empty or contain less than 4 elements.*

[TryCF.com Example](https://trycf.com/gist/2fffb71489e3210cdd83001e179e7a99/acf?theme=monokai)

```
<cfset farray = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","Q","T"]>
<cfset varray = ["11","22","33","RR","55","NN","77","68","46"]>
<cfset data   = {xOrd={},xSort={},xSel={},xMer={}}>
<cfset names  = ["xOrd","xSort","xSel","xMer"]>

<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(varray)#" index="i">
  <cfset fieldName = farray[i]>
  <cfset fieldValue = varray[i]> 
  <cfset structName = names[i%4+1]>
  <cfset data[structName][fieldName] = fieldValue>
</cfloop>
```

The substructures can be accessed through the parent, `data`.

```
<cfdump var="#data.xOrd#" label="data.xOrd">
<cfdump var="#data.xSort#" label="data.xSort">
<cfdump var="#data.xSel#" label="data.xSel">
<cfdump var="#data.xMer#" label="data.xMer">
```

Comment: Hi Ageax, I tried this exactly as you have written it.  It gave me the error:  cannot cast [xSort] string to a number value for the line <cfset parent[structName][fieldName] = fieldValue>.  Since I am unfamiliar with this approach, I'm not sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: Re your question about versions, it's sad.  I have a late version of ColdFusion on the website where this application is going to be  running.  However, I have nothing on my local machine and am developing in Lucee.  It is possible that your code would work in real ColdFusion  --  I can find out by trying it on my web based app, but possibly there is a quick answer to to the problem so that I don't need to go through that?

Comment: @BettyMock - My bad.. copied the wrong version.  Run the TryCF.com example above, that should work. I'll update it. **(Edit)** Regarding version, "late" as in old or new? If it's CF9 or above, should be able to find a matching version online or using CommandBox.

Comment: Updated the above to match the working code in the [trycf.com link](https://trycf.com/gist/2fffb71489e3210cdd83001e179e7a99/acf?theme=monokai). Tested with Lucee5 and CF10+.

Answer (score 2):

How about cfscript?

```
<cfscript>
function groupByOp(values, fieldnames) {
    var ops = ['mer', 'ord', 'sort', 'sel'];
    var byOp = {};
    arrayEach(values, function (val, i) {
        byOp["x#ops[i % 4 + 1]#"][fieldnames[i]] = val;
    });
    return byOp;
}
</cfscript>
```

This makes use of the fact that CF will automagically create structs when you mention a non-existing member.

Test:

```
<cfset v = ListToArray('1,2,3,4,5,6')>
<cfset f = ListToArray('a,b,c,d,e,f')>
<cfoutput>
    <pre>#SerializeJSON(groupByOp(v, f))#</pre>
</cfoutput>
```

outputs

```
{
    "xsel": {
        "c": "3"
    },
    "xord": {
        "e": "5",
        "a": "1"
    },
    "xsort": {
        "b": "2",
        "f": "6"
    },
    "xmer": {
        "d": "4"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I like that approach, much slicker. Was thinking something similar but wasn't sure of their version looking at the tags and history.  Only caveat I'd add is that the arrays must have *at least* 4 elements for the proper keys to be created.

Comment: @Ageax You're right Even worse, it needs to have one element *of every group*. It would be cleaner to create the top-level keys up-front.

Answer (score 2):

It's been ages i did some CF, but a tag based approach by making use of `local` scope:

```
<cfset keys = ['xord', 'xsort', 'xsel', 'xmer'] />
<cfset farray = ['f1','f2','f3','f4','f5','f6','f7','f8']>
<cfset varray = ['v1','v2','v3','v4','v5','v6','v7','v8']>

<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(varray)#" index="i">
    <cfset local[keys[i%4+1]][farray[i]] = varray[i]>
</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#xord#" />
<cfdump var="#xsort#" />
<cfdump var="#xsel#" />
<cfdump var="#xmer#" />
```

Now you have `xord`, `xsort`, `xsel` and `xmer` filled with the right key-value pairs within your `local` scope.

Comment: "making use of local scope" Actually, you can use any structure (`local`, `variables`, a new structure...). The sleeker approach is nice. One caveat, if the field/value arrays have less than 4 elements, it won't create all 4 of the variables. Don't know if that matters to the OP.

Comment: I copied your code into a small cfm but when I ran it I got the error:

Comment: Ageax, thanks for this heads up.  I tried it with shorter lists and it threw an error.  So either I have to code around that or try another method.

Comment: @BettyMock - What was the error? Their example worked for me on trycf.com with Lucee5, CF10 and 2016.

Comment: I used this arrangement: <cfset keys = ['xord', 'xsort', 'xsel', 'xmer'] />
<cfset farray = ['f1','f2']>
<cfset varray = ['v1','v2','v3']>
The error was Element at position [3] doesn't exist in array.  I guess farray had better match the keys.  I can do that.

Comment: Yeah, that's because your sample varray has < 4 elements. It'd work fine if jit had 4 or more.  Assuming the original code already validates that farray/varrays are the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Another couple of approaches.
I wouldn't necessarily say that these are better, but just different:

**Requires field array length to match value array length**

```
<cfset farray = ['field1','field2','field3','field4','field5']>
<cfset varray = ['apple','orange','pear','kiwi','pineapple']>

<cfset xord  = {}>
<cfset xsort = {}>
<cfset xsel  = {}>
<cfset xmer  = {}>

<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(varray)#" index="i">
 <cfset j = 
    ((i%4 EQ 1) ? (StructInsert(xord,farray[i],varray[i])):
    ((i%4 EQ 2) ? (StructInsert(xsort,farray[i],varray[i])):
    ((i%4 EQ 3) ? (StructInsert(xsel,farray[i],varray[i])):
    ((i%4 EQ 0) ? (StructInsert(xmer,farray[i],varray[i])): 0))))>
</cfloop>  

<cfdump var="#xord#" />
<cfdump var="#xsort#" />
<cfdump var="#xsel#" />
<cfdump var="#xmer#" />
```

OR:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(varray)#" index="i">
  <cfswitch expression="#i%4#">
    <cfcase value="0">
      <cfset xmer[farray[i]] = varray[i]>
    </cfcase>
    <cfcase value="1">
      <cfset xord[farray[i]] = varray[i]>
    </cfcase>
    <cfcase value="2">
      <cfset xsort[farray[i]] = varray[i]>
    </cfcase>
    <cfcase value="3">
      <cfset xsel[farray[i]] = varray[i]>
    </cfcase>
  </cfswitch>
</cfloop>  

<cfdump var="#xord#" />
<cfdump var="#xsort#" />
<cfdump var="#xsel#" />
<cfdump var="#xmer#" />
```

**Field array length does not have to match value array length**

```
<cfset farray = ['field1','field2','field3','field4']>
<cfset varray = ['apple','orange','pear','kiwi','pineapple']>

<cfset xord  = {}>
<cfset xsort = {}>
<cfset xsel  = {}>
<cfset xmer  = {}>

<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(varray)#" index="i">
 <cfset j = 
    ((i%4 EQ 1 AND ArrayIsDefined(farray,i)) ? (StructInsert(xord,farray[i],varray[i],true)) :
    ((i%4 EQ 2 AND ArrayIsDefined(farray,i)) ? (StructInsert(xsort,farray[i],varray[i],true)) :
    ((i%4 EQ 3 AND ArrayIsDefined(farray,i)) ? (StructInsert(xsel,farray[i],varray[i],true)) :
    ((i%4 EQ 0 AND ArrayIsDefined(farray,i)) ? (StructInsert(xmer,farray[i],varray[i],true)) : 0))))>
</cfloop>  

<cfdump var="#xord#" />
<cfdump var="#xsort#" />
<cfdump var="#xsel#" />
<cfdump var="#xmer#" />
```

OR:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(varray)#" index="i">
  <cfswitch expression="#i%4#">
    <cfcase value="0">
      <cfset (ArrayIsDefined(farray,i) ? (StructInsert(xmer,farray[i],varray[i],true)) : 0)>
    </cfcase>
    <cfcase value="1">
      <cfset (ArrayIsDefined(farray,i) ? (StructInsert(xord,farray[i],varray[i],true)) : 0)>
    </cfcase>
    <cfcase value="2">
      <cfset (ArrayIsDefined(farray,i) ? (StructInsert(xsort,farray[i],varray[i],true)) : 0)>
    </cfcase>
    <cfcase value="3">
      <cfset (ArrayIsDefined(farray,i) ? (StructInsert(xsel,farray[i],varray[i],true)) : 0)>
    </cfcase>
  </cfswitch>
</cfloop>  

<cfdump var="#xord#" />
<cfdump var="#xsort#" />
<cfdump var="#xsel#" />
<cfdump var="#xmer#" />
```

Comment: Hi Charles, your first example worked fine when I did it exactly as you wrote it.  However, when I added a fifth element to varray:<cfset varray = ['apple','orange','pear','kiwi','pineapple']> I got the error: Element at position [5] doesn't exist in array for line ((i%4 EQ 1) ? (StructInsert(xord,farray[i],varray[i])):  Does this have something to do with the last line which has a 0 after the colon?  Or something else?

Comment: Charles, the 2nd example is basically my original code with the if's changed to cases.

Comment: @Betty Mock I have updated my code. The reason you get an error, with the first example, is that the number of fields needs to match the number of values, which kind of makes sense, if you think of a database structure. I just added another field name and it works without error. You could add an extra expression in each ternary part that will ignore setting the value, if the requisite field is not available.

Comment: The reason I have chosen this approach, is that it matches the data structure parameters that you have provided in your question. The other answers are more concise but change the data structure by creating an extra array of structure names and a parent data structure. I have tried to match your exact requirements.

Comment: @CharlesRobertson - IMO, creating a single container variable isn't a big deal given how much it simplifies the code. However, agreed the 2 arrays must be the same length (or farray > varray) or errors will occur. Whether that's possible and how it should be handled (silently or validation error) depends on the app requirements, which weren't stated.

Comment: @Ageax My second set of examples do not error out, if the two arrays do not match in length. I updated this for Betty, because she originally got an error, and I wasn't aware at that point that she planned to have arrays of different lengths. In general, when the OP provides limited information, I try and work within the parameters provided. It is not right or wrong, it is just the way I do things.

Comment: @CharlesRobertson - Yeah, I noticed the second example automatically handles uneven arrays. I didn't expect that either, until I saw it in other comments. Personally, that condition seemed like an indicator something is wrong to me, so I chose to leave it unhandled, but again, all depends on the OP's requirements.

Comment: @Charles Robertson -- this update looks promising.  The number of structures to be created is always fixed -- in this case 4.  The number of items to go into those structures is variable, depending on what the user chooses.

Comment: @BettyMock - Variable number of items, sure. But would the two arrays *really* have a different number of elements - say 8 fields but 11 values? That seems odd. Under what circumstances could that happen and what would you expect the result to be in that scenario?

Comment: @Ageax, I greatly simplified the situation to ask about the core of the problem.  In reality there are exactly 5 elements of farray for every one in varray, so it is not random and we wouldn't have an 8:11 scenario.  I'm running an inner loop to accomodate that.  It comes from the user choosing what he wants over many fields each of which offers four options -- user may choose 0 to 4 of them for each field.  It's working well -- I just wish I could reduce the amount of code I've got.